# Pyspark: Aggregate data by de checking if value exist or not (not count or sum)

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a dataset like this,

```
test = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 1, 5, "2018-06-03", "Region A"),
    (1, 1, 2, "2018-06-04", "Region B"),
    (2, 2, 1, "2018-06-03", "Region B"),
    (4, 1, 1, "2018-06-05", "Region C"),
    (5, 3, 2, "2018-06-03", "Region D"),
    (6, 1, 2, "2018-06-03", "Region A"),
    (7, 4, 4, "2018-06-03", "Region A"),
    (8, 4, 4, "2018-06-03", "Region B"),
    (9, 5, 4, "2018-06-03", "Region A"),
    (10, 5, 4, "2018-06-03", "Region B"),
])\
  .toDF("orderid", "customerid", "price", "transactiondate", "location")
test.show()
```

And I can aggregate each customer's order for each region like this:

```
temp_result = test.groupBy("customerid").pivot("location").agg(count("orderid")).na.fill(0)
temp_result.show()
```

[image]

Now, insteade of `sum` or `count`, I'd like to simply aggregate the data by determining whether the value exist or not (i.e., 0 or 1), something like this

[image]

---

I can obtain the above result by

```
for field in temp_result.schema.fields:
    if str(field.name) not in ['customerid', "overall_count", "overall_amount"]:
        name = str(field.name)
        temp_result = temp_result.withColumn(name, \
                                             when(col(name) >= 1, 1).otherwise(0))
```

but is there simpler way to obtain it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically almost there - only a little tweak required to get your desired result. Within your aggregation, add the count comparison and convert boolean to integer (if necessary at all):

```
temp_result = test.groupBy("customerid")\
                  .pivot("location")\
                  .agg((count("orderid")>0).cast("integer"))\
                  .na.fill(0)

temp_result.show()
```

Results into:

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|customerid|Region A|Region B|Region C|Region D|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|         5|       1|       1|       0|       0|
|         1|       1|       1|       1|       0|
|         3|       0|       0|       0|       1|
|         2|       0|       1|       0|       0|
|         4|       1|       1|       0|       0|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

In case you get a spark error, you might use this solution instead which does the count comparison via an additional step:

```
temp_result = test.groupBy("customerId", "location")\
                  .agg(count("orderid").alias("count"))\
                  .withColumn("count", (col("count")>0).cast("integer"))\
                  .groupby("customerId")\
                  .pivot("location")\
                  .agg(sum("count")).na.fill(0)

temp_result.show()
```

Comment: The 0, 1 is important, as later I need to conver this into a matrix and perform multiplication.

Comment: `u"Aggregate expression required for pivot, found 'cast((count(orderid#469L) > cast(0 as bigint)) as int)';"`, this is what I get, did I miss something?

Comment: @cqcn What spark version do you have?

Comment: it's on databricks, 2.3.1

Comment: @cqcn1991 strange, I'm having the same version, so this shouldn't be an issue then. I provided a different solution in my answer which should work for you but it is more complicated, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. Your latest one works, but I really can't get the previous one work.

Comment: The first solution worked for me.